# How to toggle off-canvas elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my project I have to icons (phone & hamburger). Originally I had them individually triggered to add/remove classes and toggle the off-canvas menu.

The off-canvas menu (wrapper) actually holds two different menus. One one for if the user clicks on the phone icon the other a menu for when the user clicks the hamburger menu. Screenshots for reference provided.

I'm trying to refactor all that into something more managable and DRY but I'm stuck on more of the complexity of it (jQuery novice).

**Scope**

- If user clicks phone icon (changes `fa-phone` to `fa-times`), off-canvas wrapper opens

  - shows respective menu
  - if the user clicks the icon again it should revert back to `fa-phone` and remove the `fa-times` class
- If user clicks hamburger (animates to "X" - this working with `active` class and CSS) , off-canvas wrapper opens

  - shows respective menu
- If the user clicks on either icon, it should close/re-open showing correct menu
- If the user clicks anywhere on the screen, it simply closes the off-canvas element

```js
$('.js-offcanvas-toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // disable link
  $(this).toggleClass('active'); // toggle class 'active'
  $('.offcanvas').toggleClass('offcanvas__opened'); // open the menu

  if (!$(this).is('#phone-toggle')) {
    mainNav.toggle('fast'); // show the mainNav
  } else {
    phoneNav.toggle('fast'); // show the phoneNav
  }

  if ($(this).is('#phone-toggle').hasClass('fa-phone')) {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-phone').addClass('fa-times');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-times').addClass('fa-phone');
  }

});
```

```css
// Hamburger Menu
#nav-toggle {
  float: right;
}
#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.offcanvas-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .offcanvas-wrap .offcanvas {
    background-color: #e3e5e7;
    box-shadow: inset 1px -2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 17.5rem;
    padding: 25px 15px 10px 18px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
        -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
            transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease;
    height: 100%; }
    .offcanvas-wrap .offcanvas__opened {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
          -ms-transform: translateX(0);
              transform: translateX(0); }
    @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
      .offcanvas-wrap .offcanvas {
        width: 21.25rem;
        padding: 50px 30px 20px 35px; } }
/*
-------------------------
  Navigation
-------------------------
*/
.nav {
  font-family: "AvenirLT-Heavy", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.125rem; }
  .nav a {
    color: #00539b; }
    .nav a:hover {
      color: #f6b242; }
    .nav a i {
      color: #f6b242;
      vertical-align: baseline !important;
      font-weight: 700;
      float: right; }
  .nav-main > li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #00539b;
    padding: 15px 0; }
    .nav-main > li:first-of-type {
      padding-top: 0; }
    .nav-main > li:last-of-type {
      border-bottom: none; }
    .nav-main > li > a {
      padding: 0; }
    @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
      .nav-main > li {
        padding: 30px 0; } }
  .nav-main__sub {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 0.9375rem;
    font-size: 0.9375rem;
    font-family: "AvenirLT-Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
    .nav-main__sub li > a {
      padding-left: 0; }
  .nav-main__contact {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 1.875rem auto 0; }

.contact-info {
  font-family: "AvenirLT-Roman", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem; }
  .contact-info__type, .contact-info__number {
    display: block; }
  .contact-info__type {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 0.9375rem; }
  .contact-info__number {
    color: #00539b;
    font-size: 1.5rem; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="header-controls__phone">
  <i class="fa fa-phone fa-2x js-offcanvas-toggle" id="phone-toggle"></i>
</div>
<!-- END phone -->

<div class="header-controls__nav">
  <a id="nav-toggle" href="#" class="js-offcanvas-toggle"><span></span></a>
</div>
<!-- END hamburger -->

<!-- This the page markup -->

<div class="offcanvas-wrap">

  <div class="offcanvas">
    <nav class="nav">
  <ul class="vertical menu nav-main js-nav-main__primary">
    <li><a href="#">Moving &amp; Relocation <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="/overview/">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Workplace Solutions <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Logistics <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Our Capacity <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Careers <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="vertical menu nav-main js-nav-main__contact">
    <li><a href="">Get a Quote <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="/overview/">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">Send a Message<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
      <ul class="vertical menu nav-main__sub">
        <li><a href="/overview/">Overview</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Residential</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Corporate Moving</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Relocation</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Government Transferees</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Military Personnel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Call Us</a>
      <div class="nav-main__contact">
        <div class="contact-info">
          <span class="contact-info__type">Toll Free:</span>
          <span class="contact-info__number">1-NNN-NNN-NNNN</span>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-info">
          <span class="contact-info__type">Local:</span>
          <span class="contact-info__number">1-NNN-NNN-NNNN</span>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-info">
          <span class="contact-info__type">Sales:</span>
          <span class="contact-info__number">1-NNN-NNN-NNNN</span>
        </div>
        <div class="contact-info">
          <span class="contact-info__type">Support:</span>
          <span class="contact-info__number">1-NNN-NNN-NNNN</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

  </div>


  <div class="wrapper main-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <h1><!-- $siteTitle --></h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident facere, aperiam, aspernatur cupiditate consectetur amet ducimus voluptate exercitationem natus molestias eveniet non iste fuga labore pariatur molestiae optio accusamus corporis!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- End page content -->

  <!-- @include modules/need-quote -->

  <!-- @include partials/footer -->

</div> <!-- end offcanvas-wrap -->
```

[image: The two icons]

**Phone Icon Clicked**

[image: phone icon clicked]

**Hamburger Icon Clicked**

[image: hamburger menu]

Comment: Umm... so what is your question again? You want someone to refactor your code to make it manageable?

Comment: @WebWanderer - I should've be more clear in what the actual question is, apologies. The section I wrote out on the 'scope' of what I'm trying to do is essentially the question too. How would I refactor the code I've started to make this better .. as in I got stuck and it became more complex.